# print some of the result while loading

Tags: php, apache

I do not know if this is either a problem in PHP or APACHE, but I wanted to print some of the result even if the script is still running.

What I mean is, since my for loop is a long script, i wanted to print some of the finished result on that for loop. But what happens is, it will just load the page, echoing nothing, and it will just show stuffs up when the script is done loading, all at once.

P.S. That is when using wamp... when I load the script on my website online, it would print some of the results and adds some more result until the script is finished loading.

Comment: _The page has no HTML codes, pure PHP_

Comment: Your output is probably buffered

Comment: what should I do if outputs are buffered? Should I edit php.ini or httpd.conf? or just add some code to my php script?

Comment: Thank you Musa, i've searched about output-buffering, and I just turned off output-buffering on my php.ini.. All is set now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have output buffering on then add

```
ini_set("implicit_flush", "1");
```

at the beginning of your script to turn it off, this only affects the script it is in.
If you want to turn it off far the whole site set `output_buffering = Off` in php.ini
You can also do it in your .htaccess file.

Comment: How about if it is turned off, what line should I add? just change 1 to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Do all the long work in the separate scripts and use AJAX to load the needed content, you may also break the loading part into pieces.
`jQuery.get` is an easiest way to start http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

The example code will load the data into the element having `id=result` (of course you need to include jQuery http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery)

```
$.get('long_script.php', function(data) {
  $('#result').html(data);
});
```

Of course, this is a bit harder then just echoing the results in the loop, but this is guaranteed to work on any server/browser setup and also the whole page is loaded during the long task, not anyhow limiting you in html/css usage

Comment: In this case running php from command line without using Apache is probably an option (but maybe not, it depends on what you need much)